# Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEImSAQlR/libpython3.10.so.1.0'

Tags: python, loading, lib

Right now im having problem while trying to install TF2 Classic.
I am stuct at part executing TF2CDownloader, when i try to execute it it gives me this error:

[1914] Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEImSAQlR/libpython3.10.so.1.0': dlopen: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_2.30' not found (required by /tmp/_MEImSAQlR/libpython3.10.so.1.0)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

check your GLIBC version by running this command:
`ldd --version`

my centos7 shell return `ldd (GNU libc) 2.17`, so we need to update our linux version for GLIBC. for me, i should update centos7 to centos9.